# How can I check for existence of an object property?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have variable that can be `null`, `{}`.

```
if (this.data) {
     this.postaddressForm.get('index_for').setValue(this.data.index_for);
     this.postaddressForm.get('dopaddr_for').setValue(this.data.dopaddr_for);
     this.postaddressForm.get('region_id').setValue(this.data.region_id);
     this.postaddressForm.get('house_for').setValue(this.data.house_for);
     this.postaddressForm.get('locality_for').setValue(this.data.locality_for);
     this.postaddressForm.get('street_for').setValue(this.data.street_for);
}
```

Problem is that sometimes there is properties in object `data`. How to check it?

So, if there is no `street_for` it fails.

Comment: `this.data?.street_for`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843668/optional-chaining-operator-in-typescript/58221278#58221278

Comment: is it eligible ?

Comment: Why don't you just try and use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `||` to set a default parameter, and `.?` to handle `data` being undefined:

```
this.data?.street_for || ""
```